# Using LEFT JOIN on Golang and mapping to a struct

Tags: postgresql, go

I have the following structs on Go:

```
type Struct1 struct {
    ID          int64    `db:id`
    InternalID  int64    `db:internal_id`
    Structs2    []Struct2
}
```

```
type Struct2 struct {
   ID          int64    `db:id`
   InternalID  int64    `db:internal_id`
   SomeText    string   `db:some_text`
}
```

The relation between this two is: There only can be one Struct1, connect to N Struct2 by the internal_id. So I am doing this query:

```
SELECT*
FROM struct1 st1
LEFT JOIN struct2 st2 
ON
    st1.internal_id = st2.internal_id 
LIMIT 10
OFFSET (1 - 1) * 10;
```

By executing this query on Go, I wanna know if i can: Create an array of Struct1, by mapping correctly the array Struct2 on it. If it is possible, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

I'm using Postgres and sqlx.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, welcome to Stackoverflow! some questions here: what did you try already? please read this, it's very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
also, which library are you using to connect to the DB? what is the response you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely dependent on the library/client you're using to connect to the database, however, I have never seen a library support what you're trying to do so I'll provide a custom implementation that you can do. Full disclosure, I did not test this but I hope it gives you the general idea and anyone should feel free to add edits.

```
package main

type Struct1 struct {
    ID          int64    `db:id`
    InternalID  int64    `db:internal_id`
    Structs2    []Struct2
}

type Struct2 struct {
    ID          int64    `db:id`
    InternalID  int64    `db:internal_id`
    SomeText    string   `db:some_text`
}

type Row struct {
    Struct1
    Struct2
}

func main() {
    var rows []*Row
    // decode the response into the rows variable using whatever SQL client you use

    // We'll group the struct1s into a map, then iterate over all the rows, taking the
    // struct2 contents off of rows we've already added to the map and then appending
    // the struct2 to them. This effectively turns rows into one-to-many relationships
    // between struct1 and struct2.
    mapped := map[int64]*Struct1{}
    for _, r := range rows {
        // The key of the map is going to be the internal ID of struct1 (that's the ONE
        // in the one-to-many relationship)
        if _, ok := mapped[r.Struct1.InternalID]; ok {
            // Make sure to initialize the key if this is the first row with struct1's
            // internal ID.
            mapped[r.Struct1.InternalID] = &r.Struct1
        }
        // Append the struct 2 (the MANY in the one-to-many relationship) to the struct1s
        // array of struct2s.
        mapped[r.Struct1.InternalID].Structs2 = append(mapped[r.Struct1.InternalID].Structs2, r.Struct2)
    }

    // Then convert it to a slice if needed
    results := make([]*Struct1, len(mapped))
    i := 0
    for _, v := range mapped {
        results[i] = v
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)